# Error messages according to the validation patterns in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to divide the error messages according to the validation patterns,for example, in below, there are 2 patterns

`Validators.pattern(/[^ +]/),
Validators.pattern(/^[ +|a-zA-Z0-9]+$/),`

but only one message can be set.

`<md-error *ngIf="locaCd.errors?.pattern">
 onny blank is unacceptable AND must be filled by a~z,A~Z or number.
</md-error>`

Is there anyway to divide into each witout making CustomValidation??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

By default `Validators.pattern()` accepts parameter as `pattern: string | RegExp` so i will better suggest you to create you custom validation which handle a single method can handle dynamically for you.

For example `demo.component.ts`

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

this.form = new FormGroup({
   email: new FormControl('', [
    this.customPatternValid({ pattern: /[A-Z]/, msg: 'Small characters not allowed' }),
    this.customPatternValid({ pattern: /^([^0-9]*)$/, msg: 'Numbers is not allowed' })
   ]),
   password: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
   ])
});

// Create our customPatternValid function 

public customPatternValid(config: any): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      let urlRegEx: RegExp = config.pattern;
      if (control.value && !control.value.match(urlRegEx)) {
        return {
          invalidMsg: config.msg
        };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
}
```

For example `demo.component.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email"/>

  <div *ngIf="!form.controls.email.valid && (form.controls.email.dirty ||form.controls.email.touched)" class="error">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors.invalidMsg">
      {{form.controls.email.errors.invalidMsg}}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I prefer this way as well, but the question states that you should not make a CustomValidation though :/

Comment: opps sorry i miss

Answer (score 1):

Here is `ValidatorFn` that delegates validation to `Validators.pattern` but returns an object with `message` key on validation error.

```
const patternWithMessage = (pattern: string | RegExp, message: string): ValidatorFn => {
    const delegateFn = Validators.pattern(pattern)
    return control => delegateFn(control) === null ? null : { message }
}
```

With this, template can show value of `message` on validation error.

e.g. `patternWithMessage(/^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*$/, 'Invalid value for key')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same pattern expression inside your `md-error`, and separate them into two different `div`-elements, matching one and the other

**EDIT**
after testing myselv, I found that you need to execute the matching using a regepx from typescript (at least thats how I made it work)

in your component, define yout regexp

```
emptyRegExp = new RegExp(/[^ +]/);
letterNumberRegExp = new RegExp(/^[ +|a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);
```

then use those expressions in your html to display the desired error message.

```
<md-error *ngIf="locaCd.errors?.pattern">
   <div *ngIf="emptyRegExp.exec(locaCd?.value)"> Blank is unacceptable.</div>
   <div *ngIf="letterNumberRegExp.exec(locaCd?.value))">Must be filled by a~z,A~Z or number.</div>
</md-error>
```

Comment: thank you but it doesnt't work it said "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 20 in [locaCd.value.match(/[^ +]/)] in ng:///AppModule/Wa9121Component.html@14:15 ("
        </md-error>
        <md-error *ngIf="locaCd.errors?.pattern">
          <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="locaCd.value.match(/[^ +]/)"> Blank is unacceptable.</div>

Comment: I forgot to add single quotes (') around the pattern expression. Updated answer

Comment: I had no luck doing it the way I did in the beginning, so I changed the approach, using a regexp from the component instead.

Comment: thank you.... What do I need to add in this.locaCd = new FormControl('', [××××××]) then??

Comment: same as in your image. You should also add an `<md-error *ngIf="localCd.errors?.maxLength">some msg</md-error>` as well if you have not already.